# What's the approach to implement a TTL on Django model record?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ttl

Can you please tell me the approach to implement a TTL on Django model record?

For Example:Remove all values stored over more than x minutes.

Comment: How often would you like the records purged? Is the TTL set per record or for the entire table/model?

Comment: after 5 minutes.. i need both of the solution badly(both for per record and entire table

Comment: here's my code

# models.py.

class Values(models.Model):
    key=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    value=models.TextField(blank='False',default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
#serializers.py from .models import Values

class ValuesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Values
        fields=('id','key','value')

Comment: How is your app deployed? Do you already have something like celery or cron running?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you would need to do is to add a field to your model that tracks the time the record was created. Passing `auto_now_add=True` to a `DateTimeField` means that it will automatically be populated by the time the record was created

```
class Values(models.Model):

    key = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    value = models.TextField(blank='False',default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

Then you need a function that will delete records that are older than a certain age, a classmethod seems appropriate

```
    @classmethod
    def delete_old_records(cls, minutes=5):
        cut_off = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=minutes)
        cls.objects.filter(created__lt=cut_off).delete()
```

Now you need to add a method for calling this function from a script, a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) is ideal

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Deletes old Values'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Values.delete_old_records()
```

Then you need to schedule this command, something like [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [celerybeat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.beat.html) would be good for this